# Showing inequality for the norm of an integral equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, inequality, integral-inequality, integral-equations

Let $\xi \in \mathbb{R}^2$, $\Phi \in C^0([0, +\infty[, \mathbb{R}^{2x2})$ a bounded function.

Let $y:[0, +\infty[ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ a solution of the following integral equation,

$$
y(x) = e^{-x} \Phi(x) \xi + \int_0^x e^{-(x-t)} \Phi(x-t) 
\begin{pmatrix} 
  y_2^3(t) \\ 
  y_1^7(t) 
\end{pmatrix}
dt
$$

I would like to show that for each $\epsilon > 0$, $\exists \delta > 0$ such that we have,
$$
  ||\xi|| > \delta \implies ||y(x)|| < \epsilon, \quad \forall x \geq 0
$$

I tried the following steps:

1. Because $\Phi$ is bounded, $\forall x \in [0, +\infty[$, $\exists M \in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$ such that,

$$
  \Phi(x) \leq M
$$

2. Then we have the inequality,

$$
  y(x) \leq e^{-x} M \xi + \int_0^x e^{-(x-t)} M
\begin{pmatrix} 
  y_2^3(t) \\ 
  y_1^7(t) 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

3. Because $y$ is solution of the integral equation, $y$ is differentiable. Let's take the derivative with respect to $x$ on both side of the inequality,

$$
  y'(x) \leq - e^{-x} M \xi + M
\begin{pmatrix} 
  y_2^3(t) \\ 
  y_1^7(t) 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

4. I thought to apply a variation of the Gronwall lemma stating that if we have,

$$
  y'(x) \leq h(y(x)), \quad h > 0
$$

Then,
$$
  y(x) \leq H^{-1}(x - x_0)
$$
where,
$$
H(x) := \int_{y_0}^{y} \frac{1}{h(t)}dt
$$

But doesn't seem to help. Any ideas ?